# Apply grouping to a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view in my SQL Server database named `PictureCount`. I am getting data according the following query-

```
with result as
(SELECT CAST(Createddate AS DATE) AS StartDate, COUNT(ServicePictureID) AS TotalPicture 
 FROM PictureCount 
 WHERE ProjectID='11' AND 
 CAST(CreatedDate As DATE) BETWEEN '2014-10-31' AND '2014-12-05' 
 GROUP BY CAST(Createddate AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
   (CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(StartDate AS DATE)) as varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH ,CAST(StartDate AS DATE)) AS varchar)) AS StartDate, 
   TotalPicture 
FROM result
```

Data is appearing in the following format-

[image]

But I want data with group by `StartDate`. I am not able to apply `GROUP BY` clause. Please tell me if anyone knows about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you have group it with whole date i.e group by `yyyy-mm-dd`. Then, you have selected `yyyy-mm` from the date so it is working as you wrote it. I think, you want to group it by `yyyy-mm` only?

Comment: Actually first of all I am not sure where I need to write 'GROUP BY' clause. I was writing it at the last of the line like- "... with result GROUP BY StartDate" then I was getting this error- "Column 'result.TotalPicture' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
SELECT Cast(Datepart(YEAR, StartDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
       + '-'
       + Cast(Datepart(MONTH, StartDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS StartDate,
       Count(ServicePictureID)                          AS TotalPicture
FROM   PictureCount
WHERE  ProjectID = '11'
       AND CreatedDate BETWEEN '2014-10-31' AND '2014-12-06'
GROUP  BY Datepart(YEAR, StartDate),Datepart(MONTH, StartDate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, if you can show data in yyyyMM format rather than yyyy-MM. This query has less no of functions, conversions.

```
SELECT Datepart(YEAR, StartDate)*100 + Datepart(MONTH, StartDate) as yyyyMM
, Count(ServicePictureID) AS TotalPicture
FROM   PictureCount
WHERE  ProjectID = '11'
       AND CreatedDate BETWEEN '2014-10-31' AND '2014-12-05'
GROUP  BY Datepart(YEAR, StartDate)*100 + Datepart(MONTH, StartDate)
```